# Modifying a format plugin style using CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

Comments in the CKEditor documentation and its source code imply that it's possible to have some control over how styles are applied, using [addCustomHandler](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-static-method-addCustomHandler%20addCustomHandler), including for existing styles. E.g., in `core/style.js` on [line 665](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/style.js#L665) we have:

> The style handling job, which includes such tasks as applying,
>   removing, checking state, and checking if a style can be applied,
>   is very complex. Therefore without deep knowledge about DOM and
>   especially {@link CKEDITOR.dom.range ranges} and {@link
>   CKEDITOR.dom.walker DOM walker} it is impossible to implement a
>   completely custom style handler able to handle block, inline, and
>   object type styles.  However, it is possible to customize the
>   default implementation by overriding default methods and reusing
>   them.

The last sentence leads me to think I should be able to modify what happens, for example, when [the format plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/format) is used to apply a style change to convert text to an `h1` heading using something like:

```
CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler({
    element: 'h1',
    type: 1,
    apply: function( editor ) {
    console.log( 'apply' );
    },
    remove: function( editor ) {
    console.log( 'remove' );
    }
});
```

But the above, and several variations on it (with different or omitted `element` and `type` attributes) has no effect.

I guess this is either not possible or I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know which. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(Note that I can see from the docs how to have a brand new style, created with a `type` attribute and to modify it using `addCustomHandler`, but the format plugin creates its styles with the `element` attribute not the `type` attribute.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, it is possible to customize the default implementation by overriding default methods and reusing them.

You misunderstood this sentence (apologise for this, cause I'm the author :D). Using [`CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.style-static-method-addCustomHandler) you can only add new types. By overriding I meant accessing `CKEDITOR.style.prototype`. For example:

```
var originalApply = CKEDITOR.style.prototype.apply;
CKEDITOR.style.prototype.apply = function( editor ) {
    originalApply.call( this, editor );
};
```